# Disabling project refresh on build

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flexbuilder

In the Flex 3 Perspective in Eclipse, is it possible to disable the refreshing of a project after a build?  How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Adobe Support, there is no way in Flex 3 to disable any of the refreshes without breaking Flex.  Bummer.